Enable web browser's microphone access automatically
  const checkMicrophoneAccess = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      localStorage.setItem("isMicAllowed", true);
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
    }
  };

while trying to turn on automatically, getting error of "NotAllowedError: Permission denied"
How can I enable microphone access in a browser automatically from a React.js frontend application without showing the browser's default pop-up? For example, the Google Meet web application uses its own custom pop-up to manage microphone access across all browsers like Chrome, Safari etc. I need a similar flow, ideally a silent enabling process.

LUckily you cannot. Would you want an app that would silently enable your microphone, camera or what not and secretly start recording you?

@M.Deinum We need to ask the user for permission to access the microphone. Only when the user grants permission can we access it, instead of relying on the browser's default pop-up.

Well, the browser is ensuring such a popup is being shown. The browser can't just leave it up to you and trust that you will be showing such a popup and abide by it. — What Google is doing is: it's their service on their own browser. They do not need to play by their own rules. I'm not sure if it's possible to emulate that using a browser extension or not; but then the user would have to explicitly install a browser extension the first time, which is an even bigger hurdle (and rightly so).

You cannot enable the browser's microphone access automatically without showing the browser's permission notification.  This is by design and is an important security and privacy feature.
The user controls that notification, not the front-end developer.
On systems managed by an admin, the admin can set a policy to control that notification as well.


ideally a silent enabling process.

As many other permissions they must be requested on demand and approved by user each time you need them. This is security related policy. If it was not like this you can spy on user and violate user`s privacy. This is not allowed.
On trusted https domains (like from Google) user can allow usage of some devices automatically after first request and allow their usage each time code request them. But still in this case it will not be silently. Browser will indicate in address bar that code uses camera/microphone etc and user will know this.
